# redirect angularjs route in .htaccess

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess

I have an website developed on angularjs. Here i need to redirect a link like `www.example.com!#/item/1` to `www.example.com/pages/items.php?id=1`

For this i write the .htaccess dile like the folowing

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ https://www.deshshera.com/pages/items.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

It is not working. What is the right way to redirect?

Comment: You can't use `.htaccess` to remove symbols like `#` etc.

Answer (score -1):

You won't need to use your `.htaccess` file to reroute in AngularJS. Instead, in the controller of the page you want to leave, you can put this at the top:

```
 $window.location.href = '/someFolder/items.php';
```

Be sure to inject `$window` into the controller.

Using this method, the first piece of code that will be rendered by this controller will be to leave the page.